# Cloudflare broke Android SSL

Tags: android, ssl, cloudflare

I used to have a working SSL for all web and mobile browsers. After setting up Cloudflare, Android devices are unable to securely visit my site.

The error I'm receiving is:

> The identity of this website has not been verified.
>
> - Server's certificate does not match the URL.

After checking the certificate through the viewer, I noticed it is issued to `(an ssl subdomain).cloudflare.com`. Obviously, this does not match my site's URL. I cannot find solutions for this. Any fixes?

Comment: was this issue ever resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically a problem with Server Name Indication (SNI), which is used to have multiple certificates behind the same IP address. As far as I know Cloudflare uses SNI and if your application does not support it and does not send the expected server name inside the SSL ClientHello dialog it will get the wrong certificate back.

The apache HTTP library as used by android did not support SNI for a long time, which might trigger your problem. There are various posts on stackoverflow about this topic and you also find enough information online, if you search for "SNI android".